# Microsoft Digital Twins losing data?

Tags: sensors, azure-digital-twins

I tested MSDT with a number of sensors (250 and more), and found that from time to time I've got no history values for some (up to 100 in case with 250 total sensors) of my sensors. The key point is - application that sends test packet worked without interruption, so they should not be deleted by some timeout. After some time, I got all 250 sensors back there with historical data.

Fetching data was performed with just one query, I've got one big JSON with all my sensors there, but for some of them there may be no history (and current status) data, just like there was no one report for this sensor.

Has anyone faced this? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, did you say that if you did two calls to get sensors & values you would sometimes get all of the values and then immediately get a subset of the values?  I wasn't sure if "after some time" was a long time or immediately.

How long ago were the sensor values sent up to Digital Twins?  And I presume you were looking at historicalValues or were you looking at the current values?

Digital Twins doesn't store the historical values forever, the current timeout is about one day (~25 hours) and afterwards the values are purged.

Does this help?